# Hive table delimited by comma and multiple spaces

Tags: hadoop, hive, hive-serde

I have a similiar question to here:
[Hive table source delimited by multiple spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41114832/hive-table-source-delimited-by-multiple-spaces/41136732#41136732)

My data looks like this:

```
AL, 01, 2016010700,   , BEST,   0, 266N,  753W
AL, 01, 2016010706,   , BEST,   0, 276N,  747W
AL, 01, 2016010712,   , BEST,   0, 287N,  738W
AL, 01, 2016010712,   , BEST,   0, 287N,  738W
```

That means my column delimiter is "a comma plus a variable number of spaces".

I tried to simply modify `field.delim` by adding this comma to the regex, but it doesn't work.
The result is, that all data gets put into the first column (`basin`) and all other columns are NULL.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS default.myTable1
(
   basin string
  ,cy string
  ,yyyymmddhh int
  ,technum_min string
  ,tech string
  ,tau string
  ,lat_n_s string
  ,lon_e_w string 
)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.MultiDelimitSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("field.delim"=",\\s+")
LOCATION '/data';
```

I am running HDP 2.5 (Hive 1.2.1).

Thanks for any help and suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

We have two approach to solve your problem.
create table 'rawTbl' using below option

`ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','`

and use trim() to remove space

```
Insert into baseTbl select trim(basin), trim(cy),...., from rawTbl
```

OR you can use regEx

I have updated answer with regex which separate text input file composed of requested fields. Regex contains 7 regex groups capturing the requested field on each line.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABlE tableex(basin string
  ,cy string
  ,yyyymmddhh int
  ,technum_min string
  ,tech string
  ,tau string
  ,lat_n_s string
  ,lon_e_w string ) 
ROW FORMAT 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  "input.regex" = '^([A-Za-z]{2}),\s+(\d{2}),\s(\d{10}),\s+,\s([A-Z]{4}),\s+(\d{1}),\s+(\d{3}[A-Z]{1}),\s+(\d+[A-Z]{1})'
)
LOCATION '/data';
```

Comment: `input.regex` defines the columns' expressions, not the separator.

Comment: Yes, that's why I wanted to try `MultiDelimitSerDe` as the linked question indicated.

Unfortunately, using the `RegexSerDe` doesn't work:

`ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("input.regex" = ",\s+")`

I also tried it with double back-slashes: ",\\s+".
It is always giving me all columns with NULL values.

Comment: Hi :-) Better, but I would have used something like `\s*(\S*?),` instead of fixed lengh

Comment: I have one workaround : (1) create table with ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' (2) Insert into baseTbl select trim(basin), trim(cy),...., from rawTbl

Comment: I upvoted this, but only for the first part of the solution. I would be quite sad if I received the second one and had to update or troubleshoot it.

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz : What is your feedback?

Comment: I already commented ("Better, but..."), am I missing something?

Comment: @BlueElephant : please make the answer as correct if it works for you.

Comment: @ManishSarafBhardwaj: Thanks for your answer. The INSERT INTO approach works file. Altnerativley, we could simply put a view on top of it with the trim statements.

However, the second solution with the regex doesn't work for me - In my Hive version I need to write `ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.contrib.serde2.RegexSerDe'` => the keyword `SERDE` is needed in my Hive version. But all in all, I always get all columns with NULL values in it. Which Hive version are you using?

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz : I tried something similiar with `"field.delim"=",\\s+"` (and some other variants) ... your regex looks interesting to me... but I am not sure how to interpret it... can you eloborate a bit on it?
Of course, having an elegant regex to do the parsing would be perfect.

Comment: 1) `field.delim` is a single character, not regex 2) the regex means a sequence of zero or more spaces and than a sequence of zero or more non spaces

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
(\S+),\s+(\S+),\s(\S+),\s+,\s(\S+)\s+(\S+),\s+(\S+),\s+(\S*)
```

Comment: Well, it *is* an answer, but it requires some explanation. Code-only answers have very restricted value.